# How do I run automatically run a command once my program ends?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently coding on python3 and have a while True loop where it will run indefinitely so I have to force stop it for it to end. For further details, I am creating a system that automatically detects the humidity in a box, and starts a fan, once it reaches a high enough humidity. When I force stop my program, I would like it to run a command, specifically `GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)`, this will cause the fan to turn off. Any ideas? (I'm currently using a raspberry pi 3 to code this all on)

Comment: Have you tried implementing a signal handler? https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of you can detect SIGINT (Ctrl-C):

```
from time import sleep
from signal import signal, SIGINT, SIG_DFL

INTERRUPTED = False

def handler(signum, _):
    global INTERRUPTED
    signal(signum, SIG_DFL)
    INTERRUPTED = True

signal(SIGINT, handler)

while not INTERRUPTED:
    sleep(1)

print('Interrupted')
```

So here we have a potentially infinite loop but having set a handler for SIGINT we can break out of the loop upon receipt of that signal and run some cleanup code or whatever else may be necessary

Answer (score 0):

Capture an input to break out of your loop instead of manually closing the program, then put `GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)` after the loop. Or if you are set on manually ending the program perhaps manually start a separate program right after that only runs that single command?